# Calculate a specific number PHP

Tags: php

I have a for loop, where $i is 0, and it will run until $i reaches 4. I am trying to make a code that would output numbers in an order like this: 01, 11, 02, 12, 03, 13... etc... Now, the thing is next: when $i is 1, the script should make an order of those number in the boundaries of 1 and 20. When $i is 2, it would be 21 to 40, etc.

I've tried many things (mostly deleted), could not come up with anything that would work the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop:

```
for ($j = 0; $j != 10; ++$j)
{
   echo $j + 1 + 10 * ($i - 1);
   echo $j + 1 + 10 * $i;
}
```

Comment: ...what output are you looking for if `$i=0`?

Comment: @user726049: indeed, what do you expect to happen for `$i == 0`? Your description suggests the range -19 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code;

```
<?php
$num = 4;
for($i=1;$i<($num + 1);$i++){
    $string = "0" . $i . ", 1" . $i;
    if($i<$num){
        $string .= ", ";
    }
    echo $string;
} 
?>
```

Comment: I think you're missing an inner loop :P

Comment: as far as I see from the code, if $num is 0, the loop won't run at all, right?

Comment: the $num variable is whatever number you want $i to be incremented to, in this case 4

Comment: that is actually not the way it should work. in case that $i is 1, the inner loop would have to run from 1 to 20

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<?php

    $ten = 10;
    for ($i = 0; $i<=4; ++$i)
    {
       echo "0".$i." , ";
       echo $ten + $i."<br/>";
    }

?>
```

Only change the range of $i

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1124511/siberiantiger, Why are you couldn't accept my answer. I have claimed this because I'm unable to post any new question in SOF. I hope you consider.

Answer (score 0):

[`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) will format your numbers with a leading zero, as specified:

```
<?php
$format = "%02d ";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $k = 2 * $i - 1;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++) {
        printf($format, ($k - 1) * 10 + $j);
        printf($format, $k * 10 + $j);
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

?>
```